# How do I connect to local SQL Server from WSL

Tags: sql-server

I need some help here in setting up SQL Server connectivity from ubuntu 20.04.

I have followed this process:

1. Enable remote connections on the SQL Server instance
2. Enabled TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager

But when I use this command:

```bash
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P <YourPassword>
```

I get this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

Comment: `localhost` on the WSL container is the WSL container, *not* the (main) host. Try using the name of the host machine, or otherwise its IP, which is either `127.0.1.1` or `172.19.208.1` if my memory serves correctly. `etc/hosts` *should* also list the name/IP address for the host machine (from the containers perspective).

Comment: @Larnu, I don't see a hosts entry on my WSL machine that resolves to the hosting machine. The entry for my host machine references the 127.0.0.1 loopback. I can connect using the hosting machine's IP address rather than name, though.

Comment: I admit, I'm running a little on memory, @DanGuzman . My laptop has WSL enabled, but I felt it a little silly to enable WSL on Windows on my PC, considering it runs as a VM on a Ubuntu host. ;) So I can't double check my recollection.

Comment: Read [Accessing network applications with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking) , the second section (Accessing Windows networking apps from Linux (host IP)).

Comment: Hi @brian,
When I use sqlcmd -S 172.0.0.1 -U xx -P xx, it still fails, I have added Firewall rules, enabled all TCP/IP for all IPs in Configuration Manager but it is still failing. This is strange

Comment: @SikesBen Use the address from the nameserver line in /etc/resolv.conf which is certainly NOT 172.0.0.1.  Note the graphic on the right is from the Windows Host side showing that the curl in the graphic on the left connects fine.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?